# What is tRNAscan-SE bit score?

Tags: sequence-annotation, trna, trnascan-se, bitscore

I have used the command-line version of [tRNAscan-SE](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC146525/pdf/250955.pdf) by Lowe et al. (1997) on the reference genome sequence of *C. elegans* to predict tRNAs. The programme outputs a table with tRNA locations, amino acid, anti codon, intro locations, tRNA type (functional or pseudogene) along with a score. The score in my dataset ranges from 20.0 to 107.4. After reading [the article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4987944/) Lowe et al (2016) describing this tool, I still do not understand how this score comes about and what it means. I understand that:

- the higher the score, the more likely the tRNA is assigned to the correct isotype (amino acid)
- the lower the score, the more likely the tRNA is a pseudogene

My questions are:

- How is the score calculated?
- What does the score mean?

The authors of the tool state that is is 99% sensitive and detects 1 false tRNA in 15 GB of DNA. Does this mean that I do not need to filter my results? What about the confidence in the type of tRNA and whether it is functional or pseudogenised?

Lowe et al (1997) tRNAscan-SE:  a  program  for  improved  detection  of transfer  RNA  genes  in  genomic  sequence. Nuc. Acids 25
Lowe et al (2016) tRNAscan-SE On-line: integrating search and context for analysis of transfer RNA genes. Nuc Acids Web Server issue: W54–W57.